# Proper way of initializing components in Angular 2 via HTML

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've got a component that gets some parameters from outside, and then, builds the rest of its properties depending on those parameters:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

/*  
    Info card for displaying information in the homepage or another places
*/

@Component({
  selector: 'info-card',
  templateUrl: 'infocard.html'
})

export class InfoCard {
  icon;
  @Input() card = {
    title: '',
    description: '',  
    image: null,
    type: 0
  }


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

      // TODO: Complete type list
    switch(this.card.type){
        case 0:  // Pubs/Entertainment
            this.icon = "beer"; break;
        case 1:  // Restaurants
            this.icon = "restaurant"; break;
        case 2:  // Friends
            this.icon = "person"; break;
        case 3:  // Groups of people (private chats)
            this.icon = "people"; break;
        case 4:  // Objective
            this.icon = "checkbox-outline"; break;
        default:
            this.icon = "alert"; break;
    }

    // Image path
    if(this.card.image){
        this.card.image = '../../assets/infocards/'+this.card.image;
    }

  }

}
```

There you can see in the constructor, how depending on the type of the card, its icon gets set. Also, the image will only get rendered if it's different from "null", but I only want to pass from outside its name, so I put inside the constructor the real path to the folder, and concatenate the image name at the end.

Nothing strange I guess. Then, I try to use this component in my code:

```
 <info-card *ngFor="let card of testCards" [card]="card">

 </info-card>
```

The cards display "correctly". I mean, the template is rendering ok and so, but both the icon and the image, which depend of the constructor, aren't working properly. The type 0 is always present, so I always see the "beer" icon, and the image is broken (because it's not pointing to the right directory, but to a name).

This leads to the following question: when does the constructor run? I thought that an @Input value would be added before the constructor initialization, but I guess I was wrong.

What should I do to properly build my component passing its data from the HTML?

**I just want to execute some code after the property "card" has been passed to the component!**

Comment: You probably aren't using the right Attribute, Class, and Style bindings

Comment: @FabioAntunes can you explain that further?

Comment: you have to use [attr.icon]="icon" and [src]="card.image"

Comment: @FabioAntunes I guess you haven't understood the problem... not your fault, maybe I explained bad. The info is showing up perfectly, really! Thing is, that I want **some code** to work, **after** I pass the "card" parameter. That code makes some changes in the data that aren't showing up, because i'm putting it in the constructor, and it's running before the parameter gets passed.

Comment: ahhhhh ok, you want the `ngOnChanges`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-class.html) :

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

/*  
    Info card for displaying information in the homepage or another places
*/

@Component({
  selector: 'info-card',
  templateUrl: 'infocard.html'
})

export class InfoCard implements OnChanges {
  icon;
  @Input() card = {
    title: '',
    description: '',  
    image: null,
    type: 0
  }


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    //changes will have your old card value and the new one
    switch(this.card.type){
        case 0:  // Pubs/Entertainment
            this.icon = "beer"; break;
        case 1:  // Restaurants
            this.icon = "restaurant"; break;
        case 2:  // Friends
            this.icon = "person"; break;
        case 3:  // Groups of people (private chats)
            this.icon = "people"; break;
        case 4:  // Objective
            this.icon = "checkbox-outline"; break;
        default:
            this.icon = "alert"; break;
    }

    // Image path
    if(this.card.image){
        this.card.image = '../../assets/infocards/'+this.card.image;
    }
  }

}
```